# How to guarantee that Spring @Autowired injection can be accessible in the constructor

Tags: spring, code-injection

I have a Spring Bean which has a @Autowired setter getter injection. However, when i try to access injected bean, i get NullPointerException because the injected bean has not be really injected.

Is there any way to guarantee that the injection is done before constructure call?

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class A{

@Autowired
B;

public A()
{
//B is null here, because it has not been injected yet.
}

//Setter Getters
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `@PostConstruct` annotation. This will be called right after Spring initializes your bean.

```
@Autowired
B b;

public A() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void doAfterConstructorIsCalled() {
    b.do();
}
```

It's from the [javax.* API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)